# How to run command inside a tool installed on Linux

Tags: java, jsch

I'm using Putty to run custom Linux tool :

```
home> customtool; 
customtool> tool interface opens
```

Then I submit commands within the same Putty session

```
customtool> command1; 
customtool> command2;
```

Putty works great

---

Then I try to do the same with JsCH:

```
ChannelExec.setCommand("customtool; command1; command2;");
```

`customtool` executes correctly,but `command1` and `command2` doesn't work.

I think this is because command1 and command2 need to run within the customtool interface.

How to make this work in JSCH?

Comment: "command1" and "command2" must be specified as input to "customtool".

Comment: thank you. it works now it was just as you advices